# Wix Toolset. Version is not compatible

Tags: wix

I am trying to create an MSI package using the WIX Toolset 3.8.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKUqW-wCwK0&ei=Dy5QU6u0F8-ryATxpICYDg&usg=AFQjCNHkLHKEI_ntbYF_L5C7ET4zsIEE9Q&sig2=BtODmo-AaAeAPanhxmDG4Q&bvm=bv.64764171,d.aWw) and everything here works fine. When I try to run my Hello World Program I get the following error:

"The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check you computer system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher."

Looking at my Build settings For My Hello World App, Platform target is set to Any CPU.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that the installer is successfully delivering the file to the file system, but when you try to run that .exe, you see the error?

Comment: Yes the Installer is running fine and is delivering the file to the file system fine. Everything is getting place where it needs to be, but when I run the HelloWorld.exe i get that error.

Comment: Your tutorial video is set to private, needs to be updated to something that all users can view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video they set the source for both the EXE and the DLL to the TargetPath of the project. According to the [Project Reference and Variables section](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html) of the wix documentation, this would be the path of the EXE. In this case the EXE was copied, then the DLL was copied with the same name, thus overwriting the EXE.

Setting the correct source, TargetDir, for the DLL fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/08/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx). The "TL; dr." of it is -- don't pick "Any CPU" for your platform target. Most of the time, you want x86.

As a side note, WIX isn't actually related to this problem at all. It's just delivering the exe to the filesystem, and doesn't have anything to do with the execution of the payload.